# glMultiTexCoord in OpenGl ES

Tags: opengl-es

Can anyone explain how to use glMultiTexCoord() in comparison with glTexCoordPointer()?

Answer (score 1):

The `size` argument to `glTexCoordPointer()` corresponds to the suffix number of the `glMultiTexCoord()` function.

So a bunch of calls to e.g. `glMultiTexCoord3fv()` would be replaced by a single call to `glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, ...)`.

Here, the 3 is from the suffix '`3`' (size specifier), and the `GL_FLOAT` is from the suffix '`f`' (type specifier).