# GLSL - Two textures (Not mixed)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm working with textures with GLSL.
How can I handle two textures with GLSL?
One guy recommended me to do two samplers2D in my GLSL...
But how can GLSL knows which samplers2D should use? (I am not talking about mixing the textures...)

I heard that I should use glBindTexture.
How Can I do this? With glBindTexture? Anyone has an example of this?

openGL 3.3

---

Edit:

I have this:

```
uniform Sampler2D texture1;
uniform Sampler2D texture2;
```

I need to draw two objects, using textures, so how can GLSL know if he should use texture1 or texture2 according to the object I want to draw. That's my question.

Comment: The [OpenGL Wiki has an article on how this works](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29#Binding_textures_to_samplers).

Comment: @NicolBolas do you know why they use `GL_TEXTURE0 + x` in those examples instead of `GL_TEXTURE0`, `GL_TEXTURE2`, etc.?

Comment: @user1118321 Because `GL_TEXTURE#` only goes up to 31, while the *actual* limit can be much higher. You should always use `GL_TEXTURE0 + x`.

Comment: I'm confused now, please, tell me, I don't need to mix textures, I need to use that textures for different objects. Texture #1 for a pyramid, texture #2 for a box, etc...
I can bind it, that what's the people says me! That opengl wiki helps a lot, but it does not shows the frag/vert shader code....

Comment: @Spamdark: That's a *completely* different question. That's just rendering one object with one texture, then rendering a different object with a different texture. If you can render one object with one texture, then you can do it with two.

Comment: Ok, I need to use different "programs" or only one? If I only need to use one, how can this be done in the side of frag/vert and the openGL C++ code? Changing the texture uniform?

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind each texture to a different texture unit, and then use multitexture coords. It would look something like this (assuming you already have the textures) :

```
glActiveTexture (GL_TEXTURE0);  // First texture is going into texture unit 0
glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex0);
glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glActiveTexture (GL_TEXTURE1);  // Second texture is going into texture unit 1
glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE2D, tex1);
glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glUseProgram (yourGLSLProgramID);
glUniform1i (sampler1Location, 0); // tell glsl that sampler 1 is sampling the texture in texture unit 0
glUniform1i (sampler2Location, 1); // tell glsl that sampler 2 is sampling the texture in texture unit 1
///... set the rest of your uniforms...

glBegin (GL_QUADS);
    glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);

    glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertexCoord2f(width, 0.0);

    glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertexCoord2f(width, height);

    glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertexCoord2f(0.0, height);
glEnd();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use openGL 3.3.

Comment: OK, so the only difference would be not using `glBegin()`/`glEnd()`. Instead you'd use a array of coordinates for the various texture units.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524736/glmultitexcoord-in-opengl-es) for info on how to use `glTexCoordPointer()` instead of `glMultiTexCoord()`.